# can't access javascript object value

Tags: javascript

I have an object which I can see all the values in the console but when I try to access specific item it throws undefined error.

[image]

If I do `obj['PHPSESSID']` I get the value but `obj['HNKSTHOUSFHS']` is undefined error. What am I doing wrong?

```
function readCookie(key){
    var arr = document.cookie.split(';');
    var obj = {};
    $.each(arr, function(index, value){
        value = value.split("=");
        obj[value[0]] = decodeURIComponent(value[1]);
    });
    return obj[key];
}

console.log(readCookie('HNKSTHOUSFHS'));//undefined
```

Comment: Please don't provide text as an image. Copy and paste actual text, which can in turn be copied and pasted if necessary.

Comment: Chances are the key is `" HNKSTHOUSFHS"` (note the space prefix). You should probably `trim()` the `value`

Comment: The key has a space in front of it.

Comment: Take a look at this comprehensive *cookie framework* ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework

Comment: Thanks @Phil and gladsocc. That was the prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function readCookie(key){
    var arr = document.cookie.split(';');
    var obj = {};
    $.each(arr, function(index, value){
        value = value.split("=");
        obj[value[0].trim()] = decodeURIComponent(value[1].trim());
    });
    return obj[key];
}
```